# reading an xml file line by line with c# gives a reverse output

Tags: c#, xml

My code is below. The xml file I used is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J8njqxti4N8CTdbqZFs9GovhzDwpNaay).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadingAnXMLFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("D:/C#/GameAssets/Images/alienExplode/images/alienExplode.xml");
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                Console.Write(xmlReader.Name);
                while (xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                    Console.Write(" " + xmlReader.Name + " = '" + xmlReader.Value + "' ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            Console.ReadKey(); // wait for keyboard input to exit
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is in the reverse order from the data in the xml file. For example The xml file line shows

```
<SubTexture height="25" width="24" y="474" x="180" name="explosion0000.png"/>
```

whereas my console output is

```
SubTexture name = 'explosion0000.png'  x = '180'  y = '474'  width = '24'  height = '25'
```

Any idear why this happens?

Comment: I opened your XML file and saw that lines are the same as console output:

`<SubTexture name="explosion0000.png" x="180" y="474" width="24" height="25"/>`

Your output looks like ok. But I advice to see [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k1h0k3e.aspx).

Comment: yes but in reverse order. J_Kay's answer below solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual implementation of `MoveToNextAttribute()` is recursive, which returns the last (deepest) element first.
The nature of XML Attributes is that they are order-independent, so you should design without that expectation in mind.

From [MSDN:](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlNodeReader.cs)

```
public override bool MoveToNextAttribute() {
            if ( !IsInReadingStates() || nodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement )
                return false;
            readerNav.LogMove( curDepth );
            readerNav.ResetToAttribute( ref curDepth );
            if ( readerNav.MoveToNextAttribute( ref curDepth ) ) {
                nodeType = readerNav.NodeType;
                if ( bInReadBinary ) {
                    FinishReadBinary();
                }
                return true;
            }
            readerNav.RollBackMove( ref curDepth );
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags), XML attribute order is not significant, so the `MoveToNextAttribute()` order is arbitrary. They may have chosen that direction so that you can remove attributes while looping with `MoveToNextAttribute()`. If order matters to you, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xmlReader.AttributeCount; i++) //or (int i = xmlReader.AttributeCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) for the reverse order
{
    xmlReader.MoveToAttribute(i);
    //...
}
```

Comment: That may work in practice, but I very much doubt it is guaranteed by the spec. The general rule is that XML parsers deliver attributes in any order they choose.